# PHP glob() in bracketed directories

Tags: php, glob

On a Windows machine, the following script:

```
<?php

mkdir("c:\\[test]");
file_put_contents("c:\\[test]\\test.txt", "some content");
chdir("c:\\[test]");
echo getcwd()."\n";
var_dump(glob('*'));

?>
```

Displays this:

```
C:\[test]
array(0) {
}
```

When this is expected:

```
C:\[test]
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "test.txt"
}
```

I understand that `glob` treats brackets as special characters, *when found in the `pattern` parameter.*

The pattern `*` matches any file in the current working directory. However, glob() 
behaves as though it was run with the pattern `c:\\[test]\\*`

The brackets are then being interpreted as part of the pattern, when in fact they 
are part of the directory.

**Is `glob` supposed to treat the *path* as part of the *pattern*?** I would rather think it should use the current directory as a starting point, and then process the *pattern only*.

(Attempt to summarize): The `glob` function acts like it's getting `c:\\[test]\\*` as a match pattern, and is trying to match either `c:\t\*`, `c:\e\*`, or `c:\s\*`. But the pattern is actually `*` and it shouldn't be trying to match any of that.

Comment: I can not replicate this on Mac, can you check is the directory and file is really created properly on your window?

Comment: could i suggest the obvious, don't use [] in dir names?

Comment: @Dagon Why [] can't be used in dir names?

Comment: @Dagon - Sometimes a script must work with an environment in which there are pre-existing bracket-named directories.

Comment: @ajreal - Yes, I have checked everything extensively. The problem exists as stated, at least on Windows machines.

Comment: How about `glob('*.txt')` ? and `globl('c:\\\[test\]\*')`

Comment: @ajreal - I'm not looking for workarounds, I'm looking for the "why" :)

Comment: Oh, because you did not escape back slashes (as simple as this) ... and notice the difference for string parsing in double quote vs single quote (you example is using double quote)

Comment: @ajreal - What backslashes are not properly escaped in my example above?

Comment: `To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\). To specify a literal backslash, double it (\\). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.`

Comment: @ajreal - You haven't answered my question. What wasn't escaped properly *in my example*??

Comment: @Unsigned I guess you not sure what you have done wrongly. Can you do `getcwd()` right after `chdir()`?

Comment: @ajreal - I have updated the example script and output dumps with the `getcwd` call as you suggested.

Comment: @Unsigned sure ... on glob `On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.`, so you really have to try try `glob('*.txt') ? and globl('c:\\\[test\]\*')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be covered as an issue in this bug report on php.net: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33047

The last post on that thread is about it not being a bug, but an issue from how glob treats brackets, as part of the regular expression. I'm not sure I agree. It seems you can work around this, unless you cannot move up into the parent folder.

If you remove the first requirement of being in the inside [test] folder, you can get the file listing by using a syntax like below:

```
chdir('..');
$glob = glob("[[]test[]]/*");
```

Given these complications, I would recommend not using the glob function if you are running into issues on windows machines, and look at other file listing functions like [readdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php).

Comment: That's not really "the conclusion", it's just the last comment posted so far, and unless I'm missing something the comment is plain wrong. Whatever, it looks like a valid bug report, although it's already closed without a fix.