# Glob doesn't return results

Tags: php, glob

I'm probably doing something wrong but I can't find what.

Here is the code that works:

```
foreach (glob('uploads/'.$userid.'[*') as $file)
{
  echo $file."<br>";
}
```

And here what I am trying to make it work but it doesn't:

```
foreach (glob('uploads/'.$userid.'[?]('.$id.')*') as $file)
{
  echo $file."<br>";
}
```

Some file examples:

```
uploads/24[3](30) Random name.pdf
uploads/24[1](114) Random name.pdf
uploads/24[2](55) Random name.doc
etc etc
```

Basically: `UserID[1-3](ID) name of the file`

Comment: put some sample of your file structure and the files names.

Comment: @hassan I've update the question. Thanks

Comment: how do you define your `$id` variable ?

Comment: Both userid and id are taken directly from the DB. The thing is even if I write it as `glob('uploads/'.$userid.'[3](*')` it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

glob function :

> The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern
>   according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, **which is
>   similar to the rules used by common shells**.

you need to escape your brackets and parentheses as follows :

```
foreach (glob('uploads/'.$userid.'\[?\]\(' . $id . '\)*') as $file) {
    echo $file."<br />";
}
```

Comment: I've just tried that but it still doesn't return anything :/

Comment: from my side : `root@hassan:/var/www/# php list.php`
output : `uploads/24[1](114) Random name.pdf
uploads/24[2](55) Random name.doc
uploads/24[3](30) Random name.pdf`

Comment: try this `glob('uploads/'.$userid.'\[?\]\(*\)*'` and I am sure that it will works fine, maybe the issue from your variables , print out them and see

Comment: I literally copy pasted and it doesn't print out any results :(

Comment: and what about `'uploads/'.$userid.'\[*\]\(' . $id . '\)*'`

Comment: and for testing purposes , try this absolute path and see `'uploads/24[2](55)*'`

Comment: please check for any other errors in your code, put this at top of your code , `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` and let's see

Comment: and before your foreach loop echo this `'uploads/'.$userid.'\[?\]\(' . $id . '\)*'` and reply with the response

Comment: The absolute path doesn't work. I don't see any kind of error with error_reporting and the echo returns: `uploads/24\[?\]\(55\)*`

Comment: It seems like the [ ] are the problem. I just manually changed them into ( ) and it worked. No idea why [ ] keep failing though.

Comment: you are using windows or linux ?

Comment: Currently Windows

Comment: I ended up with an alternative instead: `'uploads/'.$userid.'?[1-3]?(' . $id . '*'`

Comment: this is weird behavior of glob, but maybe because you are using windows https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33047 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/10501407/2359679